# Complete background pattern coded from CSS

Tags: css, background-image

I am trying to rely on more code than images with my web design and in my effort to be more effective in HTML5 and CSS3.

I have searched all Stack Exchange sites but nothing solid resulted. That being said, something I would really like to learn more about is pattern creation with pure CSS for website backgrounds.

***I was wondering if this can be created with pure CSS coding?***

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

CSS3 does not have the ability to create patterns on the level that you have in mind. CSS pattens are very basic and use small blocks of patterns to build up a large scalable/repeatable block based background.

**CSS patterns are basic your image is not basic**

The image that you have used does not repeat and is more suitable for using it as a: `{background: url("background.jpg");}` or you could use [Base64 and embed the image to the CSS file](http://webcodertools.com/imagetobase64converter).

**Creating basic patterns using C33**

There is various ways you can make CSS3 Patterns on the fly using JavaScript/CSS and CSS3. I recommend you check out this article: [CSS3 Patterns Explained](http://24ways.org/2011/css3-patterns-explained/), or another method of making simple patterns using Base64 embeds is using [Patternify](http://24ways.org/2011/css3-patterns-explained/).

Answer (score 3):

Using the latest browsers (except Internet Explorer) and CSS3, you **can** create background patterns using just CSS and no images.    These techniques won't be useful in the real world for several years until IE supports it and the current IE browsers stop being used.

Here is a site that has a collection of CSS3 backgrounds: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/
They don't have one that is exactly like yours, however the carbon fiber one is a gray pattern that isn't too different: http://lea.verou.me/css3patterns/#carbon